# Create windows 8.1 installation USB Uefi

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a custom ISO for Win 8.1 x64 with size around 7gb. Inside the ISO there's a file install.esd that is about 5.6 GB.
I try to create A UEFI install USB ( FAT32) using RUFUS , but I get an error message that the iso contains file larger than 4GB and can't be copied to Fat32.

What can I do ?
Thank you !

Comment: Extract the files from the .iso then burn those

Comment: can't copy a file >4GB to a Fat32 partition. and UEFI usb require Fat32.

Comment: [Some solutions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/20/creating-bootable-usb-drive-for-uefi-computers.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that I have install.esd not install.wim. Is possible to split a ESD file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Rufus with NTFS.

Yes, it **DOES** work. Do not believe the reports that say that *"UEFI requires FAT32"* because this is simply just wrong. UEFI can boot from any type of file system, as long as you have the relevant UEFI driver, and Rufus will set up a bootable NTFS driver for you.

For more, please see [UEFI:NTFS](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs).

The only issue you may face is that Rufus is not compatible with `install.esd` (only `.wim`).